# How to SuperClass object cast to SubClass [objective -c]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add polyLine to mapView , the baidu mapView polyline superclass is BMKPolyLine, it have a class method:

```
+ (BMKPolyline *)polylineWithPoints:(BMKMapPoint *)points count:(NSUInteger)count;
```

I creat a subclass BKMyPolyLine, i add a @property colorString

when I get points and used superclass method  :

```
BKMyPolyLine *myLine = [BKMyPolyLine polylineWithPoints:points count:points.count];

myLine.colorString = colorString;
```

and crash message:

```
[BMKPolyline setColorString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x138266fe0'
```

Comment: you seem to fail to understand what a cast is. A cast is just making the compiler believe that the object is of a certain type. It does NOT transform the object to that class you are casting it to. So even if you cast it to a class it doesn't have the subclass' specific methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't "casting" (casting merely informs the compiler; it does not alter actual types)--but you *have* done something that should return your subclass. It sounds like `BMKPolyline`'s `+polylineWithPoints:count:` method returns a `BMKPolyline`, even when it's called on a subclass. Instead you need to override what's known as the "designated initializer", which should be marked in the documentation. But from what I see online, it *isn't* documented--you probably (annoyingly) need to look into the source of `BMKPolyline` to know how to proceed.